# What is wrong with solution to the 23'th task of go tour?

Tags: go

There is a go tour. I've solved https://tour.golang.org/methods/23 like this:

```
func (old_reader rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    const LEN int = 1024
    tmp_bytes := make([]byte, LEN)
    old_len, err := old_reader.r.Read(tmp_bytes)
    if err == nil {
        tmp_bytes = tmp_bytes[:old_len]
        rot13(tmp_bytes)
        return len(tmp_bytes), nil
    } else {
        return 0, err
    }
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Where `rot13` is correct and debug output right before return shows correct string. But why there is no output to console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Read` method for an `io.Reader` needs to operate on the byte slice provided to it. You're reading into a new slice, and never modifying the original.

Just use `b` throughout the Read method:

```
func (old_reader rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := old_reader.r.Read(b)
    rot13(b[:n])
    return n, err
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Output parameters is evil :(

Comment: It's kind of hard to make use of a pre-allocated read buffer, if you don't pass it as a parameter.

Comment: This code isn't quite right (although it'll work for a `strings.Reader`) -- `Read` may return an error and a non-zero `n`, and when it does this decoder won't decode the result. `n, err := old_reader.r.Read(b); rot13(b[:n]); return n, err` is more accurate.

Comment: From https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader : "Callers should always process the n > 0 bytes returned before considering the error err. Doing so correctly handles I/O errors that happen after reading some bytes and also both of the allowed EOF behaviors."

Comment: @PaulHankin:yes, I returned `n` for that reason, but forgot to rot13 any read bytes. In my rush I also needlessly reassigned `b`. The fixed answer is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You're never modifying `b` in your reader.  The semantic of `io.Reader`'s `Read` function is that you put the data into `b`'s underlying array directly.

Assuming the `rot13()` function also in-place modifies, this will work (**edit**: I've tried to keep this code close to your version so you can see what's changed easier.  JimB's solution is a more idiomatic solution to this problem):

```
func (old_reader rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    tmp_bytes := make([]byte, len(b))
    old_len, err := old_reader.r.Read(tmp_bytes)
    tmp_bytes = tmp_bytes[:old_len]
    rot13(tmp_bytes)
    for i := range tmp_bytes {
        b[i] = tmp_bytes[i]
    }
    return old_len, err
}
```

Example (with stubbed `rot13()`): https://play.golang.org/p/vlbra-46zk

On a side note, from an idiomatic perspect, `old_reader` isn't a proper receiver name (nor is `old_len` a proper variable name).  Go prefers short receiver names (like `r` or `rdr` in this case), and also prefer camelcase to underscores (underscores will actually fire a `golint` warning).

**Edit2**: A more idiomatic version of your code.  Kept the same mechanism of action, just cleaned it up a bit.

```
func (rdr rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    tmp := make([]byte, len(b))
    n, err := rdr.r.Read(tmp)
    tmp = tmp[:n]
    rot13(tmp)
    for i := range tmp {
        b[i] = tmp[i]
    }
    return n, err
}
```

From this, removing the `tmp` byte slice and using the destination `b` directly results in JimB's idiomatic solution to the problem.

**Edit3**: Updated to fix the issue Paul pointed out in comments.

Comment: You should use an early return pattern to remove the `else` clause and indentation of the main code path. There's no need to allocate the extra slice, use the provided slice. If you do need to copy, use the `copy` built-in to copy bytes rather than a for-loop.

Comment: Yep, like I said in the edit, I intentionally tried to keep the changes to his code to the minimum necessary to make it functional, so the differences are more easily seen.  It's very much not ideally idiomatic Go.

Comment: This code has a similar problem to JimB's: `Read` may return n>0 and err != nil (eg: err = io.EOF) and when it does, you truncate the result.